# Find Duplicates from tree list in Dev-Ex

Tags: devexpress

I have a Dev-Ex Tree List which has two columns, List contains elements inside it, Now My question is if i want to add any new item in the list then logic should search existing items in the tree, if no match found then it should allow to add that item in the list,otherwise not.
can i make a method which keep on checking recursively new item with the other item in the list.

Comment: Maybe others know but what is Dev-Ex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such tasks are usually solved by using TreeList Iterator.  I think that the [How to Implement an Iterator for the XtraTreeList (FindNode Example)](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/kb/p/A236.aspx) knowledge base article contains the code you are looking for.